# text position not correct for TikZ, automata

Tags: beamer, automata

Here is the code to generate state machine:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Power lost during upgrade}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3.5cm]
    \node[initial,state,accepting] (B)    {$ON$};
    \node[state] (A) [above right of=B]   {$ASC0$};
    \node[state] (F) [left of=A]          {$FOTA$};
    \node[state] (U) [below right of=A]   {$ACM0$};

    \path[->] (B) edge node [pos=0.5, sloped] {c1} (A)
              (B) edge node [red, pos=0.5, sloped] {c2} (F)
              (A) edge [loop above] node {$10s$} (A)
              (A) edge [bend left, pos=0.5, sloped, below] node {reset} (B)
              (A) edge node [red, pos=0.5, sloped]{timeout} (U)
              (U) edge [loop right] node {forever}
              (U) edge [bend left, pos=0.5, sloped, above] node {reset} (B)
              (F) edge [bend left, pos=0.5, sloped, above] node {reset} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It looks ok but two points have problem, I use red color to highlight them. I already used `pos=0.5` and `sloped` but seems not correct.

[image]

Then I found a way to overcome it, just changed the two problematic lines to:

```
...
(B) edge node [red, sloped, anchor=center, below] {c2} (F)
...
(A) edge node [red, sloped, anchor=center, above]{timeout} (U)
...
```

May I know why these two lines of code need be different than other?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have two problems, one is `auto` and the other is that your are mixing `edge` and `node` options like in

```
(A) edge [bend left, pos=0.5, sloped, below] node {reset} (B)
```

which should be

```
(A) edge [bend left] node[pos=0.5, sloped, below] {reset} (B)
```

It seems that `auto` doesn't use `north` or `south` anchors for placement of edge labels on edge's mid point. It affects `timeout` and `c2`, but also `c1`. I don't know why, but you can avoid this problem, suppresing `auto` from your `tikzpicture` declaration a positioning each label `above` or `below` as you want. In this case `pos=0.5` is not needed.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Power lost during upgrade}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth', shorten >=1pt, node distance=3.5cm]
    \node[initial,state,accepting] (B)    {$ON$};
    \node[state] (A) [above right of=B]   {$ASC0$};
    \node[state] (F) [left of=A]          {$FOTA$};
    \node[state] (U) [below right of=A]   {$ACM0$};

    \path[->] (B) edge node [sloped, above] {c1} (A)
              (B) edge node [red, sloped, below] {c2} (F)
              (A) edge [loop above] node {$10s$} (A)
              (A) edge [bend left] node[sloped, below] {reset} (B)
              (A) edge node [red, above, sloped]{timeout} (U)
              (U) edge [loop right] node {forever}
              (U) edge [bend left] node[sloped, below] {reset} (B)
              (F) edge [bend left] node[sloped, above] {reset} (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]